# What exactly does the == operator do?

Tags: c#, operators, cil, comparison-operators

So I took a look at ILDASM, inspecting a .exe which looks like this:

```
int a = 2;
Int32 b = 1;
if(b == 1)
{

}
```

Now, the CIL code looks like that:

```
IL_0005:  ldloc.1
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0007:  ceq
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
IL_000a:  ceq
IL_000c:  stloc.2
```

I understand that first b is loaded (which is stored at [1]), then a constant with the value of 1 and then they are compared. What I do not understand is why another constant with the value 0 is loaded and compared, before the result of that comparison is stored.
Since the first compare should already produce a truth value, checking if this value is 0 inverts the result, right?
My question is now: why is it inverted?
I assume it has something to do with the == operator that I used and my theory is that it returns the difference. If this difference is 0, the values are the same, so true should be the result. But 0 stands for false, so it needs to be inverted.
I just can't seem to find anything about this topic, just something about operators like ==~ or the likes. 
Hope you can enlighten me :)

Best regards

Wilsu

PS: This is the full code:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void  Form1_Load(object sender,
                                                class [mscorlib]
System.EventArgs e) cil managed
{
// Code size       19 (0x13)

.maxstack  2
.locals init ([0] int32 a,
       [1] int32 b,
       [2] bool CS$4$0000)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2
IL_0002:  stloc.0
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0004:  stloc.1
IL_0005:  ldloc.1
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0007:  ceq
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
IL_000a:  ceq
IL_000c:  stloc.2
IL_000d:  ldloc.2
IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0012
IL_0010:  nop
IL_0011:  nop
IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Form1::Form1_Load
```

Comment: I don't get that IL at all. My guess is it's from another piece of the code. Please post a short but *complete* example.

Comment: I get the same (at least similar result) with only this code inside main.

Comment: are you compiling in release? (I don't see any "nop", but...), and: is this the *entire* code? It looks like it has done some fun re-ordering ;p But: I don't see a 3rd variable, so it isn't obvious to me what `stloc.2` even *means*...

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that you're looking at a debug build; the short answer there is: it does a lot of unnecessary stuff *to make debugging easier*. You shouldn't pay too much attention to the IL from debug builds.

Comment: This is not the complete code. I started at IL_0005, there's 4 lines above this and also .maxstack 2 and .locals init. Rest of the code is too long for comment though... I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing a jump to the end of the function, as far as I can gather.

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 2;
    Int32 b = 1;
    if(b == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Gives me:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0005:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0006:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0007:  ceq         
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  ceq         
IL_000C:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_000D:  ldloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_000E:  brtrue.s    IL_001D
IL_0010:  nop         
IL_0011:  ldstr       "A"
IL_0016:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_001B:  nop         
IL_001C:  nop         
IL_001D:  ret
```

Starting from IL_0005, we have:

Load `b`.
Load `1`.
`ceq` (If equal, push `1`, if false push `0`) - Result here will be `1`
Load `0`
`ceq` - Result here will be `0`
`brtrue.s    IL_001D` - If value is non-zero, jump to `IL_001D` (end of function)

So it's essentially compiled to this:

```
int a = 2;
Int32 b = 1;
if(!(b == 1))
    goto end;
Console.WriteLine("A");
:end
return;
```

Comment: for context, when I compile this (optimized) I get: `ldc.i4.1`, `ldc.i4.1`, `bne.un.s {to the ret}`, `ldstr "A"`, `call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)`, `ret ` - very different

Comment: although frankly I'm kinda disappointed that it didn't remove that completely and compile to `ret`, since comparing two constants at runtime seems ... dumb

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

`ceq` takes two values from the stack and results in `1` if they are considered equal, and `0` if they aren't. However, whether `==` in C# results in `ceq` depends on a lot of things:

- the data types

  - are they primatives?
  - do they have custom `==` operators?
  - are they references?
- the context

  - can it be optimized to something else? (I get a `bne.un.s` in a similar example; there is also `beq*`, `br*`, `switch`, etc)
  - can it be removed completely?

Comment: Regarding the data types: that's why I used integers. Primitive data types, no overloaded operators. It never crossed my mind that something so presumably simple like the == operator could be optimized any further... you got me interested, I'll take a look at whatever bne.un.s is now. Thank you for your time.